# Explorer in Wagtail does not show any pages

Tags: wagtail

I have two instances of identical code (development and production), and I find this issue happening only on the production. I deployed both to a virgin instance, meaning there was no Wagtail installation before that.

The Wagtail admin shows like I have no pages. I do have 2 pages, and even if I didn't have shouldn't there be a "Welcome to Wagtail Page" (it usually is and it was on my development instance). Furthermore, it looks like there is a portion of a site missing.

[image]

That is all I see, no matter how many pages I have created (I create them trough URL)

**Edit:**
This is the full stack trace in the log

```
2017-04-21 10:27:08,898 exception 22370 ERROR Internal Server Error: /admin/pages/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 43, in _cache_controlled
    response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/decorators.py", line 24, in decorated_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/pages.py", line 104, in index
    'do_paginate': do_paginate,
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
 File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 314, in render
    if match:
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 112, in __len__
    return len(self.object_list)
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/opt/..../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/query.py", line 380, in specific_iterator
    pages = model.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: Looks like there's a template error on the page, causing a section to be silently skipped (Django's default behaviour in production mode). Can you try adding `'debug': True` to your `TEMPLATES` setting (as per https://gist.github.com/gasman/e0a9cb8c133db3e17c8e614e4fac883d) and see if that gets you a more informative error?

Comment: You are right. The error is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'`, which is not really that descriptive. From what I can find it originates from `defaulttags.py` and then the paginator throws this error since it doesn't have any pages to go trough.

I can post a full traceback, but would rather move this conversations to regular answers than comment.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback. Unfortunately we can't move this conversation to an answer until I have enough information to actually write one :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, I've found that this error occurs when you've removed a page model definition from your project, but pages of that type still exist. (Wagtail *should* be able to gracefully handle this situation - the fact that it doesn't is a bug, and I'll file an issue shortly...)

You can track this down by running the following lines on the `./manage.py shell` command line:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

[(ct.id, ct.app_label, ct.model) for ct in ContentType.objects.all() if ct.model_class() is None and ct.app_label != 'wagtailadmin']
```

Hopefully this will give a result like:

```
[(2, u'home', u'homepage')]
```

showing the content type ID, app label and model name of the missing page type.

To get the admin working again, run the following lines (making sure to replace `2` with the content type ID from the result above):

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

Page.objects.filter(content_type_id=2).update(content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='wagtailcore', model='page'))
```

This will convert the affected page(s) into Wagtail's basic 'Page' type (which has no content fields other than 'title') - you can then go ahead and delete this page.

Comment: This, in fact, did solve my problem. Thank you. Could you post the link to the issue as well, so I can keep my eye on the fix and see if I can maybe help out with a PR.

Comment: Good to know it's sorted! The issue is https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3567, and I now have a tentative PR (awaiting review) at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3569.

Answer (score 1):

For me, @sagman's solution worked with minor changes. Discovered you will get a ModuleNotFoundError if you input *wagtail.wagtailcore* in the Shell but have *wagtail.core* in INSTALLED APPS, you need to enter *from wagtail.core.models import Page* in the Shell instead of *wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page*. Everything else works as illustrated by @gasman.